# error using datalisting react-redux-datatable package

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express, mern

In the view I put all code for datatable and also using react redux method ,when I run this code then give me error look like this :

> Your render method should have return statement 
>   react/require-render-return

How to fix it?

service.js file

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import DataTable from 'react-redux-datatable';
import 'react-redux-datatable/dist/styles.css';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import {Link} from 'react-router-dom';
import {getServices} from '../../actions/servicesActions';
import Spinner from '../Spinner';

class Services extends Component{
    componentDidMount(){
    const api= this.props.getServices();
} 
render(){

    const services=this.props.services;

    var tableSettings = {
    tableID: 'AdvancedFeaturesTable',
    wrapperType: 'section',
    displayTitle: 'Requests Table',
    keyField: '_id',
    defaultSort: ['_id', 'desc'],
    minWidth: 880,
    useLocalStorage: true,
        tableColumns: [
            {
              title: '_id',
              key: '_id',
              width: 90,
            },
            {
              title: 'Name',
              key: 'name',
              width: 90,
            },
            {
              title: 'Description',
              key: 'description',
              width: 90,
            }, 

            {
              title: 'Status',
              key: 'status',
              width: 164,
            },
            {
              title: 'Subscription',
              key: 'subscription',
              width: 90,
            },
        ],
    };

    var DataTable = () => (
        <DataTable
          tableSettings={tableSettings}
          apiLocation={services}
        />
    )
}
};

const mapStateToProps = state => {    
    return {
        service: state.services.service
    };
};
export default connect(
    mapStateToProps,
    {
        getServices
    }
)(Services);
```

getservices.js

```
export  const getServices=() =>dispatch => {
dispatch(setLoading());
axios.get('/api/admin/services')

.then(res =>

    dispatch({ 
        type:GET_SERVICES,
        payload:res.data
    })
)

  .catch(err =>
  dispatch({
    type: GET_SERVICES,
    payload: {}
  })
)
}
```

error display

```
 Line 199:  Your render method should have return statement  react/require-render-return
```

referral link
    https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-redux-datatable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is clear. A component in react must return a jsx element or set of jsx elements.

In your Services component the render method isn’t returning anything

Looks like you want Services component to render DataTable so replace below code in your Services component render

```
render(){
  const tableSettings = {
      tableID: 'AdvancedFeaturesTable',
      wrapperType: 'section',
      displayTitle: 'Requests Table',
      keyField: '_id',
      defaultSort: ['_id', 'desc'],
      minWidth: 880,
     useLocalStorage: true,
     tableColumns: [
        {
          title: '_id',
          key: '_id',
          width: 90,
        },
        {
          title: 'Name',
          key: 'name',
          width: 90,
        },
        {
          title: 'Description',
          key: 'description',
          width: 90,
        }, 

        {
          title: 'Status',
          key: 'status',
          width: 164,
        },
        {
          title: 'Subscription',
          key: 'subscription',
          width: 90,
        },
    ],
};

return(
    <div><DataTable
      tableSettings={tableSettings}
      apiLocation={this.props.services}
    />
  </div>
   )}
```

This will resolve your issue.

Comment: thanx render error is now gone but one more is display like this:-       Could not find "store" in either the context or props of "Connect(DataTableContainer)". Either wrap the root component in a <Provider>, or explicitly pass "store" as a prop to "Connect(DataTableContainer)".  if you know why arise this error please give solution

Comment: You need to pass redux store as a prop to Provider component to fix the new issue. Please share its relevant code here or ask in a new question will look into it. Please upvote and accept the answer If your primary issue is resolved.